# Performing an "if any true" check on boolean column in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, summary

I'd like to find out if there's a way to summarize a boolean without iterating through the rows of the DF. I have a situation like this one:

```
Label | Attribute  
Item1 | False  
Item1 | False  
Item2 | False  
Item2 | True  
Item3 | True  
Item3 | False
```

I'd like to summarize like so:

```
Label | Attribute  
Item1 | False  
Item2 | True  
Item3 | True
```

with some kind of "if any are true" argument. I've been composing a summary table with groupby & methods (max) etc for other types of attributes, and I can create a summary by iterating through, but of course I'd rather avoid if there's an easier way.

Comment: Try `df.groupby('Label')['Attribute'].any()`

Comment: you can do the equivalent of what @ChrisA suggested with `df.set_index('Label').Attribute.any(level=0)`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisA & piRSquared, those work perfectly!

Comment: Thanks ChrisA & @piRSquared, those work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `describe()` method which is useful for summarising a data frame.

```
df.groupby('Label')['Attribute'].describe()
```